# MySQl Setting user variables

Tags: mysql, variables

I have this SQL code

```
SELECT
    (@counter := @counter +1) AS "counter",
    a1.*
FROM
    my_table AS a1, (SELECT @counter := 0) AS a2
```

and other queries with the same use of variables.
This works fine but returns a warning:

"Setting user variables within expressions is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
Consider alternatives: 'SET variable=expression, ...', or 'SELECT expression(s) INTO variables(s)'"

I can't re-write query with variable but without warning.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: mysql 8 has ROW_NUMBER for this, Besides a rownumber without an order makes no sense

Comment: What version of MySQL do you use? Since version 8.0 window functions are supported, `row_number()` among them, which is the clean way of doing what you do with that variables work around.

Comment: Yes MySQL 8.0 has window function and row_number() but this is an example query, I have different query with N variables that I use like this query.
I want to know if there is a different syntax thet remove warning.

Comment: check all the window function if one doesn't fir, user variables will get deprecated